# Heap buffer overflow

Tags: c++, linux, heap-memory, heap-corruption

After adding one boolean variable to class declaration application crashes whenever accessing that variable. All I do is just initializing the variable.

```
Ui::SliderWidget::SliderWidget(QWidget *parrent)
: QWidget(parrent),
  m_slider(nullptr),
  m_main_layout(nullptr),
  m_counter_lbl(nullptr)
  // m_disable(false)
{
    this->setObjectName("SliderWidget");
    this->initialize();
    // m_disable = false;
}
```

After removing the comment application crashes with message "AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow" and "Shadow memory range interleaves". Any read or write on m_disable cause problem. This problem occurs in linux. On Windows everything works fine. Bellow is the output.

```
> =================================================================
==5579==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60700014fd58 at pc 0x0000004e55c7 bp 0x7ffc0dddea70 sp 0x7ffc0dddea60
WRITE of size 1 at 0x60700014fd58 thread T0
    #0 0x4e55c6 in Ui::SliderWidget::SliderWidget(QWidget*) ../livemonitornew/Ui/sliderwidget.cpp:17
    #1 0x503b2f in Ui::Settings::GameOptions::create_widgets() ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/gameoptions.cpp:73
    #2 0x503acf in Ui::Settings::GameOptions::initialize() ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/gameoptions.cpp:65
    #3 0x503795 in Ui::Settings::GameOptions::GameOptions(QWidget*) ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/gameoptions.cpp:32
    #4 0x50b1bf in Ui::Settings::Preferences::create_tabs() ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/preferences.cpp:174
    #5 0x50a8fd in Ui::Settings::Preferences::initialize() ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/preferences.cpp:100
    #6 0x50a452 in Ui::Settings::Preferences::Preferences(QWidget*) ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/preferences.cpp:40
    #7 0x44d9ff in Ui::ControllerWidget::create_widgets() ../livemonitornew/Ui/controllerwidget.cpp:180
    #8 0x44cf76 in Ui::ControllerWidget::initialize() ../livemonitornew/Ui/controllerwidget.cpp:101
    #9 0x44c419 in Ui::ControllerWidget::ControllerWidget(QWidget*) ../livemonitornew/Ui/controllerwidget.cpp:35
    #10 0x42c9ec in Controller::initialize() ../livemonitornew/controller.cpp:105
    #11 0x42c4c5 in Controller::Controller(QSharedPointer<QSharedMemory>, QMainWindow*) ../livemonitornew/controller.cpp:74
    #12 0x438399 in main ../livemonitornew/main.cpp:42
    #13 0x7fbc7632f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
    #14 0x42c168 in _start (/home/mher/Documents/workspace/build-LiveMonitor-Desktop_Qt_5_6_2_GCC_64bit2-Debug/LiveMonitor+0x42c168)

0x60700014fd58 is located 0 bytes to the right of 72-byte region [0x60700014fd10,0x60700014fd58)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fbc794d4532 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x99532)
    #1 0x503b1f in Ui::Settings::GameOptions::create_widgets() ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/gameoptions.cpp:73
    #2 0x503acf in Ui::Settings::GameOptions::initialize() ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/gameoptions.cpp:65
    #3 0x503795 in Ui::Settings::GameOptions::GameOptions(QWidget*) ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/gameoptions.cpp:32
    #4 0x50b1bf in Ui::Settings::Preferences::create_tabs() ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/preferences.cpp:174
    #5 0x50a8fd in Ui::Settings::Preferences::initialize() ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/preferences.cpp:100
    #6 0x50a452 in Ui::Settings::Preferences::Preferences(QWidget*) ../livemonitornew/Ui/Settings/preferences.cpp:40
    #7 0x44d9ff in Ui::ControllerWidget::create_widgets() ../livemonitornew/Ui/controllerwidget.cpp:180
    #8 0x44cf76 in Ui::ControllerWidget::initialize() ../livemonitornew/Ui/controllerwidget.cpp:101
    #9 0x44c419 in Ui::ControllerWidget::ControllerWidget(QWidget*) ../livemonitornew/Ui/controllerwidget.cpp:35
    #10 0x42c9ec in Controller::initialize() ../livemonitornew/controller.cpp:105
    #11 0x42c4c5 in Controller::Controller(QSharedPointer<QSharedMemory>, QMainWindow*) ../livemonitornew/controller.cpp:74
    #12 0x438399 in main ../livemonitornew/main.cpp:42
    #13 0x7fbc7632f82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow ../livemonitornew/Ui/sliderwidget.cpp:17 Ui::SliderWidget::SliderWidget(QWidget*)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c0e80021f50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd
  0x0c0e80021f60: fd fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c0e80021f70: fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c0e80021f80: fd fd fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa
  0x0c0e80021f90: fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa
=>0x0c0e80021fa0: fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]fa fa fa fa
  0x0c0e80021fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 fa fa fa fa fa fd fd
  0x0c0e80021fc0: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd
  0x0c0e80021fd0: fd fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c0e80021fe0: 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c0e80021ff0: fd fd fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Heap right redzone:      fb
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack partial redzone:   f4
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
==5579==ABORTING
```

There is only 6 instance of `SliderWidget` and `sizeof(SliderWidget)` is 72 byte. They are all constructed in heap without problem until reading or writing on `m_disable`. Valgrind memory analyzer reports 'Invalid write of size 1' warning. Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Try increasing the stack size.

Comment: There's something undefined somewhere, but it's very difficult to guess where. It does sound suspiciously like there being two conflicting definitions of `SliderWidget`, though. If there aren't, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: Observing behavior like you describe, I would imagine that somewhere else you have memory problems like hanging pointers, uninitialized data etc. You need to perform a static code analysis and a code review of the relevant area of your SW.

Comment: ... check also the places where a placement operator new is used if any. Besides that would be interesting the occurrence of the crashes, and the value of `this` in the constructor of your class (you can just `printf("%p", this)` it).

Comment: Clang static analyzer shows no errors and no warnings. Also there is no placement new, and cleaning and rebuilding is done.

Comment: Here is the output of this
`Ui::SliderWidget(0x1e6b420, name="SliderWidget")`
`Ui::SliderWidget(0x1e72570, name="SliderWidget")`
`Ui::SliderWidget(0x1ef9d70, name="SliderWidget")`
`Ui::SliderWidget(0x1f3c230, name="SliderWidget")`
`Ui::SliderWidget(0x1fba780, name="SliderWidget")`
`Ui::SliderWidget(0x1fc13c0, name="SliderWidget")`

Comment: How can it be related to stack size? @MNS

Comment: @MherDidaryan It could be due to the fact that presence of `m_disable` causes a crash and its absence doesn't cause a crash. It is possible that when the it tries to allocate memory for the boolean variable on stack it can run out of space.

Comment: Could it be a build problem? Some translation units use the changed definition while some others don't...